# Product Array Puzzle

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

**Problem:** You are given an array of ‘N’ integers. You need to return another array ‘product’ such that ‘product[i]’ contains the product of all the arrays except the element at the ith position in the given array.

**Note:**
As the product of elements can be very large you need to return the answer in mod (10^9+7).

**My Code**

```
vector < int > productPuzzle(vector < int > & arr, int n) {
   
   vector<int> output;
   int product = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        product*=arr[i];
        output.push_back(product);
    }
    product = 1;
    for(int i=n-1;i>0;i--){
        output[i] = output[i-1]*product;
        product *= arr[i];
    }
    output[0] =product;
    return output;
}
```

**Doubt**: I am not getting all the test cases passed. I think the issue is with handling large products. Could anyone help to suggest what changes should I make to get all test cases passed?

Comment: Can you give an example of a test case that you are not passing?

Comment: n= 18
Array Elements: 41 60 11 19 38 58 32 10 33 48 86 33 74 16 42 84 59 17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to take modulo every time you calculate multiplications to prevent overflow.

Also casting to a 64-bit (or more) type is required if `int` is not capable to store the product before taling modulo.

```cpp
vector < int > productPuzzle(vector < int > & arr, int n) {
   const int MOD_BY = 1000000007;
   
   vector<int> output;
   int product = 1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        product=(static_cast<long long>(product) * arr[i]) % MOD_BY;
        output.push_back(product);
    }
    product = 1;
    for(int i=n-1;i>0;i--){
        output[i] = (static_cast<long long>(output[i-1])*product) % MOD_BY;
        product = (static_cast<long long>(product) * arr[i]) % MOD_BY;
    }
    output[0] =product;
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain how "static_cast<long long>" works and how is it different from just long long?